# 2nd function in toggle function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to toggle the width of an element on click of another.

I've used the script someone has made here: http://jsbin.com/ohOZEYI/1/edit?html,css,js,output

and just replaced it with my own elements:

```
function a(el){
    $(el).animate({width: "10%"}, 1500);
}
function b(el){
    $(el).animate({width: "100%"}, 1500);
}

$("#mybtn").click(function() {
    var el = $('#container');
    return (el.t = !el.t) ? a(el) : b(el);
});
```

The first function (a) works fine and shrinks the element to 10% width. But the 2nd function doesnt work.

Would anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `jQuery` function doesn't return DOM nodes. It returns an object that contains a *collection* of DOM nodes.

```
var el = $('#container');
```

creates a new instance of an object which happens to contain a reference to the DOM node with an ID of `container`. Every time the function gets called, you get a brand new instance of `el`, which means your toggle can never toggle.

To fix this, you're going to want to store the toggle data on the DOM node.

Use the [`.data()` method](http://api.jquery.com/data):

```
var t = el.data('toggle');
if (t) {
    a(el);
} else {
    b(el);
}
el.data('toggle',  !t);
```